# Request goes through but it doesn't update database

Tags: laravel, sql-update, crud, laravel-8

I'm doing a laravel crud, everything was going well until it didn't. Now it seems my update function is not working. Unfortunately, I'm not running tests, so I don't know WHEN it started to fail. I made my crud with a crud generator so it did work until recently.

**This is my Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $week = Carbon::now()->weekOfYear;
    $loggedid = Auth::id();
    $semaforoVenta = SemaforoVenta::find($id);

    return view('semaforo-venta.edit', compact(['semaforoVenta','loggedid','week']));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param  SemaforoVenta $semaforoVenta
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, SemaforoVenta $semaforoVenta)
{
    request()->validate(SemaforoVenta::$rules);

    $semaforoVenta->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('semaforo-ventas.index')
        ->with('success', 'SemaforoVenta updated successfully');
}
```

The odd thing is, I have the same lines on my other Controller, and that one is working smoothly. So I checked my model because I thought I may be missing my fillable, but nope.

**Model**

```
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','week_id','marca_o_empresa_visitada','contacto','puesto','correo','telefonos','propuesta','veces_compartidas','venta_prospectada','pagado','dia'];
```

**And this is my form**

```
<div class="box box-info padding-1">
<div class="box-body">

<div class="form-group" hidden>
        {{ Form::label('user_id') }}
        <input type="number" value="{{$loggedid}}" 
        {{ Form::text('user_id', $semaforoVenta->user_id, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('user_id') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'user_id']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('user_id', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" hidden>
        {{ Form::label('week_id') }}
    <input type="number" value="{{$week}}" 
        {{ Form::text('week_id', $semaforoVenta->week_id, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('week_id') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'week_id']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('marca_o_empresa_visitada') }}
        {{ Form::text('marca_o_empresa_visitada', $semaforoVenta->marca_o_empresa_visitada, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('marca_o_empresa_visitada') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Marca O Empresa Visitada']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('marca_o_empresa_visitada', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('contacto') }}
        {{ Form::text('contacto', $semaforoVenta->contacto, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('contacto') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Contacto']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('contacto', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('puesto') }}
        {{ Form::text('puesto', $semaforoVenta->puesto, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('puesto') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Puesto']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('puesto', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('correo') }}
        {{ Form::text('correo', $semaforoVenta->correo, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('correo') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Correo']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('correo', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('telefonos') }}
        {{ Form::text('telefonos', $semaforoVenta->telefonos, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('telefonos') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Telefonos']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('telefonos', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('propuesta') }}
        {{ Form::text('propuesta', $semaforoVenta->propuesta, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('propuesta') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Propuesta']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('propuesta', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('veces_compartidas') }}
        <input type="number" min="0" step="1"
        {{ Form::text('veces_compartidas', $semaforoVenta->veces_compartidas, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('veces_compartidas') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Veces Compartidas']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('veces_compartidas', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('venta_prospectada') }}
        <input type="number" min="0" step="1"
        {{ Form::text('venta_prospectada', $semaforoVenta->venta_prospectada, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('venta_prospectada') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Venta Prospectada']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('venta_prospectada', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check {{ $errors->has('pagado') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="pagado" value="0"/>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="pagado" name="pagado" value="1" {{'pagado', $semaforoVenta->pagado === 1, 'checked' }}/>
            <label for="pagado" class="form-check-label">Pagado</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('dia') }}
        <input type="date"
        {{ Form::text('dia', $semaforoVenta->dia, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('dia') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'placeholder' => 'Dia']) }}
        {!! $errors->first('dia', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>

</div>
<div class="box-footer mt20">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**And this is my SemaforoVenta Class**

```
/**
 * Class SemaforoVenta
 *
 * @property $id
 * @property $user_id
 * @property $week_id
 * @property $marca_o_empresa_visitada
 * @property $contacto
 * @property $puesto
 * @property $correo
 * @property $telefonos
 * @property $propuesta
 * @property $veces_compartidas
 * @property $venta_prospectada
 * @property $pagado
 * @property $dia
 * @property $created_at
 * @property $updated_at
 * @package App
 * @mixin \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
```

Also, when I run a dd($request) it does show me the data I changed, but no changes occur in my database. 'SemaforoVenta updated successfully' pops up after clicking submit, but it doesn't really update.
Any ideas? This is my first CRUD so, things are probably messy.

Comment: I think there is no id mentioned for updating that record the update query not able find specific record's id in query enter update query with id it will work

Comment: Do you get any errors or what happens after you submit the form? As you are getting your changed values from the Request object, the issues lie either in validation or update method. It would be easier to understand if you share your SemaforoVenta Class as well.

Comment: @zihad I do get a success message 'SemaforoVenta updated successfully' after clicking submit. I updated my post to show my SemaforoVenta Class as well.

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh how can I implement this? I did this with a crud generator and it worked perfectly before, I don't know how that generator handled ids, but it still works on my other controller.

Answer (score 0):

if the data is arriving in your request, try updating in this way

```
$semaforo_venta =  SemaforoVenta::findOrFail($reques->id);
$semaforo_venta->field_1 = $request->property1;
$semaforo_venta->field_2 = $request->property2;
$semaforo_venta->update();
```

remember that this is an example, so in "field_1" it will be your database field and filled by the corresponding request property.
if the id of the element is not arriving in the request. Send it from your sight

Comment: I tried this method but it did exactly the same as my old method $semaforoVenta->update($request->all());
WEIRDLY ENOUGH, I changed $semaforo_venta->update(); to $semaforo_venta->save();
and it created a duplicate on my db, with the only difference being the field I changed.

Comment: Sorry. In the instance use SemaforoVenta::findOrFail($request->id);since in this case, it is updating. Get the id of the item you are going to update in your db. I have edited the answer

Comment: I get error 404 when using $semaforoVenta = SemaforoVenta::findOrFail($request->id); after submiting ):

Comment: Pero logró actualizar el item? Luego de updatear revise su  return redirect()->route('semaforo-ventas.index')
        ->with('success', 'SemaforoVenta updated successfully');

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't update after clicking submit. It just shows the 404 error page and nothing changes.